Scaling and Helmholtz equation
Solutions to Laplace equation and powers thereof have some convenient invariance properties that solutions to Helmholtz equation $\Delta u-u=f$ apparently lacks, especially in regards to scaling, while specialists refer to the "Homogeneous scaling properties of the Helmholtz equation", "Helmholtz equations that scales" and "Scaling invariance (of the Helmholtz equation) under suitably chosen boundary conditions". What are some of its general implications, and what are its interpretations? The Helmholtz equation per se is not a central topic of mine nor is any of the preceding themes. References are most welcome.
